# Show/hide options from dropdown using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have 3 dropdowns which contains more than 4 questions as options in each dropdowns. What I want to achieve is when a user selects one option from any dropdown, that particular option/question has to be hidden from other 2 dropdowns and when he changes his selection that option/question has to be shown again in the other 2 dropdowns. **He can select questions from any dropdowns**. Here is what I have tried till now. This particular piece of code will hide the options on select but I am not getting how exactly I can show it up back.

**Javascript**

```
var removeSelection = function (select) {
$('select').filter(':not(#' + select.attr('id') + ')').each(function () {
    var index = select.find(':selected').index();
    $(this).find('option:eq(' + index + ')').hide();
});
};

$(function () {
    $('select').change(function () {
        removeSelection($(this));
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="form1">
 <select id="select1">
     <option id="selectOpt1">Question 1</option>
     <option id="selectOpt2">Question 2</option>
     <option id="selectOpt3">Question 3</option>
     <option id="selectOpt4">Question 4</option>
 </select>

    <select id="select2">
        <option id="selectOpt1">Question 1</option>
        <option id="selectOpt2">Question 2</option>
        <option id="selectOpt3">Question 3</option>
        <option id="selectOpt4">Question 4</option>
    </select>

    <select id="select3">
        <option id="selectOpt1">Question 1</option>
        <option id="selectOpt2">Question 2</option>
        <option id="selectOpt3">Question 3</option>
        <option id="selectOpt4">Question 4</option>
    </select>



</form>
```

**JSFIDDLE-**
[CLick Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/wtgt4be9/)

**Updated Fiddle**
[Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/wtgt4be9/4/)

**Scenario 1 - Select one option from any dropdown.It should be disabled from other dropdowns.
Scenario 2 - Change option from same dropdown. Previous option should be enabled in other dropdowns.**

Comment: you can use to disable them instead of hide

Comment: @Kaushik You cannot hide select > option. you can only disable it.

Comment: `id` should be unique. Use `class` instead.

Comment: @ShahRukh.. Either of them is ok.. I dnt have problem with disabling. I am stuck up with enabling the same when option has been changed from parent dropdown.

Comment: I'm able to select the same option in all 3 drop downs in your demo. di you check whether it's working or not?

Comment: @TilwinJoy..Yep.. it was working fine... :o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you change the duplicate `id`'s to  common classes, You can try something like this

```
$('select').change(function () {
    $("option:disabled").prop("disabled",false); // reset the previously disabled options
    var $selectedQ = $(this).find("option:selected"); // selected option
    var commonClass= $selectedQ.attr("class"); // common class shared by the matching options
    $("."+commonClass).not($selectedQ).prop("disabled","disabled"); // disable the matching options other than the selected one
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/wtgt4be9/1/)

(*This won't work if there are more than one, different classes for the options, i'd use a common value or data attribute instead like*)

```
$('select').change(function () {
  $("option:disabled").prop("disabled", false);
  var $selectedQ = $(this).find("option:selected")
  var value = $selectedQ.val();
  $("option[value='" + value + "']").not($selectedQ).prop("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/wtgt4be9/2/)

**Update** (*as per comments*)

```
$('select').change(function () {
  var prevMatches = $(this).data("prevMatches");
  if (prevMatches) prevMatches.prop("disabled", false)
     var $selectedQ = $(this).find("option:selected")
  var value = $selectedQ.val();
  var $matches = $("option[value='" + value + "']").not($selectedQ);
  $matches.prop("disabled", "disabled");
  $(this).data("prevMatches", $matches);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/wtgt4be9/6/)

Comment: Hey Tilwin.. This enables the first selected option after I select the one more option from other dropdown...

Comment: @Kaushik I read you comment for the other answer, you want it to be like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/wtgt4be9/3/)?

Comment: Well 75% correct. Still it will not enable other options on some point of time. Let me show you how!


Select Question 3 from First Dropdown.
Select Question 4 from Second Dropdown.
Select Question 2 from Third Dropdown.

Now all the dropdowns will have Question 1 as enabled option.

If I select Question 1 in the Thrid dropdown. Question 2 shuold be enabled for all the dropdowns. This is how I want it.

Comment: Bingo.. Even this is exactly what I want. Thanks alot for the answer.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var removeSelection = function (select) {
var id=select.attr("id");
$(".hide-"+id).show();
$('select').filter(':not(#' + select.attr('id') + ')').each(function () {
    var index = select.find(':selected').index();

    $(this).find("option").removeClass("hide-"+id);
    $(this).find('option:eq(' + index + ')').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("id")!="selectOpt1"){
        $(this).addClass("hide-"+id);
    }
});
});
$(".hide-"+id).hide();
```

};

```
$(function () {
    $('select').change(function () {
    removeSelection($(this));
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhalse/kktx3cqm/2/)

Comment: Well this meets my requirements partially. First if I select Question 3 from first dropdown, it will be removed from other 2. Then if I select Question 2 from 2nd dropdown and Question 4 from 3rd dropdown, Question 1 must be always there in all the dropdowns. When I select Question 1 again in 1st dropdown, First selected option Question 3, will not be shown again in other 2 dropdowns...

Comment: Ok, I didnt get that from the question, now it is updated to allways show option 1.

Comment: No no. you got it wrong. Let me update my fiddle and let u explain scenario. Question 1 is not default. Lets say I have first option as -Select Question-. and 4 questions in each dropdowns. Scenario 1 - The one selected in any dropdowns should be disabled in other dropdowns.
Scenario 2 - If the selection gets changed it should be enabled back in other dropdowns too.. Hope you got it.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look

```
               <form id="form1">
        <select id="select1">
         <option     value="Question1">Question 1</option>
            <option value="Question2" >Question 2</option>
            <option  value="Question3"  >Question 3</option>
            <option  value="Question4"  >Question 4</option>
        </select>
<select id="select2">
         <option     value="Question1">Question 1</option>
            <option value="Question2" >Question 2</option>
            <option  value="Question3"  >Question 3</option>
            <option  value="Question4"  >Question 4</option>
        </select>

    <select id="select3">
         <option     value="Question1">Question 1</option>
            <option value="Question2" >Question 2</option>
            <option  value="Question3"  >Question 3</option>
            <option  value="Question4"  >Question 4</option>
        </select>




     </form>





               $(document).on('change','select',function(e){
                     var elm = $(this);
                     elm.find('option').show();
                     $('select').not(elm).find('option',each(function(){
                        if($(this).attr('value')==$(elm).val()){
                             $(this).hide();
                         }else{
                                 $(this).show();
                         }
                     }));



                });
```